# Why isn't my class program working? (python)

Tags: python, function, class, if-statement

I'm trying to make a class with function statement so I can learn how to make cleaner code. I keep getting 'userInput' is not defined when I defined it in my main program. Why?

"""

```
class ShippingCharges:
    def __init__(self, userInput=None):
        self.userInput = userInput


    def getPrice (self):
        if (userInput <= 2):
            return("Package", packNum," will cost $1.10 per pound")
        elif(6 < userInput > 2):
            return("Package", packNum, " will cost $2.20 per pound")
        elif(10 < userInput >6):
            return("Package", packNum, " will cost $3.70 per pound")
        elif(userInput > 10):
            return("Package ", packNum, "will cost $3.80 per pound")

    def displayPrice(self):
        print(getPrice)

        

def main():
    #introduction
    userName = input("Hello, what is your name? \n")
    print("\nHello" , userName, "welcome to the Fast Freight Shipping Company self service.")
    
    x = 0
    userResponse = "y"
    packNum = 1
    
    while(x != 1):
        userInput = eval(input("Enter the weight of package: "))
        if(userInput >0):
            package = ShippingCharges(userInput)
            package.getPrice()
            package.displayPrice()
            packNum = packNum + 1
            userResponse = input("Would you like to send another package? y/n \n")
            if(userResponse == "n"):
                break
        elif(userInput <= 0):
            print("Package must be greater than 0")

    print("\nThank you", userName, "for our this services.")              


main()
```

why do I keep getting (name 'userInput' is not defined) when it clearly is defined in my program?

Comment: Don't do `eval(input(...))`, do `float(input(...))`.  (Or, for a fun trick, try entering something like `exit()` at the "enter the weight" prompt...)

Answer (score 2):

Change `userInput` to `self.userInput` as it is a class variable